# How to get datetime from web service or from my last update in android?

Tags: android, sqlite, datetime, calendar

Okay guys, here is the thing, i got an application, that is consuming ODATA service via SMP server, i need to get this data and save in my local database: After that,

What i need to do, is get the last time that i update my localdatabase, or/and get the last update from the server(I don't know what is the best solution, or more easy) if you could helpe-me the two solutions will be appreciated !!!

The question is im my Sqlite, probably i can use a simple calendar/date from android ?? and im my server i need to configure something to my application get this datetime ?

Just to resume I want to save the current date in my local db for future consults, suppose i just finished to upload my database from a WebService and i got new data right ? 
I wants to save this current date and when the person wants to see when they got the last update a toast via click button will return the last update, not necessary periodically or nothing much complex... simple stuff

And also, how can insert datetime value in SQLite database, and consult the last row updated ??

Comment: What is exactly your question? Do you want to implement time based synchronisation?

Comment: Like not exactly, I want to save the current date in my local db for future consults, suppose i just finished to upload my database from a WebService and i got new data right ? I wants to save this date and when the person wants to see when they got the last update a toast via click button will return the last update, not necessary periodically or nothing much complex... simple stuff   thanks man

Comment: Why don't you just save the timestamp in preference file?

Comment: PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit().putLong("lastUpdatedTime", new Date().getTime()).apply();

Comment: PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getLong("lastUpdatedTime", 0L);

Comment: Okay, got it, but can you Chk, please tell me how i'm able to hang this ?? like how can i peform an alert with this, 
or how to show this message to the user,
or how to save this in a database only designated to date time,
and at least how to send this to a web service ?? 

like my question is i know how to make these stuff, but i don't know how to hang these method like, i need a Variable to save the timestamp then perform my action ??

thanks...